# how to access website hosted on Xampp server through my ip address instead of local host

Tags: networking, web, xampp, localhost, ip-address

I've installed xxamp. what i am looking for is i want to access xamp/htdocs/index.php through my IP address not from local host. can any One tell me step by step procedure ? thank you ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that xxamp uses Apache (since I've only used wamp) there is configuration file that you can modify: httpd.conf
There should be a line that says "ServerName  local host" add a '#' sign in front of it start a new line and type "ServerName (your IP address)" without the quotes and without the parathensis and insert your IP address. I THINK you have to put :80 at the end of your IP.

I did this with wamp, and accessed my files through my tablet and other devices with a router.